# ASP.net MVC Routing: Is it good style to use QueryStrings?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

Should all routes in ASP.net MVC follow a "Only slashes, no QueryString" philosophy?

I'm working on a Wiki software, so I have routes like

```
/{pageTitle}
/{pageTitle/Edit
/{pageTitle/History
```

etc. for all actions, but what if I want to control the behavior of an Action? Is something like

```
/{pageTitle}?noredirect=true
```

okay or considered bad practice? If the latter, is there a better option? Should I create a separate route

```
/{pageTitle}/NoRedirect
```

instead?

I think it's clean, but then again I've never written a complicated MVC application that would need passing options to the action before :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe there's no definite answer to this.

But to me, it feels more natural to just have controller & action related parts in the left part of the URL and have the "optional" parameters in the QueryString.

While it's clear that ;

- `/{pageTitle}` will show the article ,
- `/{pageTitle}/Edit` will edit the artice,
- `/{pageTitle}/History` will show the history of that artice

`/{pageTitle}/NoRedirect` doesn't really ring a bell.
But it's a bit more obvious that `/{pageTitle}?noredirect=true` modifies the behaviour of the action.

So I would go with `/{pageTitle}?noredirect=true` in your case.